# Console Error with Azure Mobile Services invokeAPI call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am integrating my Angular App with a Azure Services back end.

I initially was just using the standard $http call like this:

```
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "https://services.example.com/Api/myApi",
      headers : {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "my-key"
      },
      data : post,
      success : function(data,status) {
        console.log(data + "  " + status);
      },
      failure : function(err) {
          console.log(err)
      }
```

But this was strangely returning a 200 response, yet throwing a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource Error. The Back End developer assured me that CORS was open, so lost there.

Then tried to integrate with https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-azure-mobile-service. The integration made sense, and the call looks like this:

```
Azureservice.invokeApi('myApi', {
          method: 'post',
          body: {
             data: 'Cheese'
          },
          headers : {
             'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
          }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
          console.log('Here is my response object');
          console.log(response)
      }, function(err) {
          //console.error('Azure Error: ' + err);
      });
```

And I get the undescriptive error:
OPTIONS https://services.example.com/api/myApi MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2

t.DirectAjaxTransport.t.performRequest @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2t.Platform.t.webRequest @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2t.MobileServiceClient.MobileServiceClient._request @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2t.Platform.t.async @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2Promise @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2t.Platform.t.async @ MobileServices.Web-1.1.2.min.js:2invokeApi @ angular-azure-mobile-service.min.js:1$scope.submit @ form.js:30$a.functionCall @ angular.js:10567(anonymous function) @ angular.js:18627$get.h.$eval @ angular.js:12412$get.h.$apply @ angular.js:12510(anonymous function) @ angular.js:18626n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4435n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4121

Plus the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header error again, with a 404!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st problem: You are doing a cross domain request through your angular js code. So you will have to allow your angular site in your Azure mobile service setting. Go to your mobile services dashboard > configure > app settings > create a setting "MS_CrossDomainOrigins", the value should be "http://[yoursitename]". You could allow multiple sites like this "http://[site1],http://[site2]", but your ajax call doesn't look like it's calling a Mobile Service even though the tag suggested you are asking about Mobile Services. Anyway, you should use a browser debugger like Chrome inspector and check the response whether it has the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" or not. If not, you need to go back to your backend developer. (The Microsoft documented way of allowing CORs through webapiconfig didn't work for me when I published it, so maybe he is doing the same. It only worked when I debugged.)

2nd problem: I think you really need to figure out the CORs issue first. One at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was pretty sure this did boil down to being a CORS issue, but I am new to Azure, so I was not sure if I was missing something on my front end.

Comment: You are welcome. So it did end up being COR issue? Glad I could help but it looked like you were calling an Azure management API so I wasn't sure my mobile service instruction helped.

Comment: Yes it was clearly a CORS issue. I was able to get access to the Azure Admin Portal and found that the allowed origins was set, but the CORS also required accepted headers as well.